# Using `std::copy()` with `std::back_inserter()`

Tags: c++, c++11, copy, std

I have two class A and B both have a member like below:

```
class A {
  ...
  std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<size_t>>> grid;
}

class B {
  ...
  std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<size_t>>> grid;
}
```

I found when I use `std::copy()` to copy from `A::grid` to `B::grid`, it will fail.
Here is what I do:

```
// Here is in B's constructor.
// I initialize B::grid with the same size of A::grid
grid = vector<vector<vector<size_t>>>(GetSetting().grid_cols());
for (int i = 0; i < GetSetting().grid_cols(); i++) {
  grid[i] = vector<vector<size_t>>(GetSetting().grid_rows());
  for (int j = 0; j < GetSetting().grid_rows(); j++) {
    grid[i][j].reserve(a.grid[i][j].size());
  }
}

// Copy from A to B
std::copy(a.grid.begin(), a.grid.end(), std::back_inserter(grid));
```

But if I remove initialize part, then the std::copy will work fine.
What's wrong for the initialize part?

Comment: Why on earth are you not doing simply `grid = a.grid;`?

Comment: @ T.C. , I also tried to use operator=() and it works correctly. I just want to know what's wrong as I use std::copy  :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Let me show you with a simplified example.

```
std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3};
std::vector<int> v1;
std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(v1));
```

In this scenario v1 will be 1, 2, 3, as expected. Now consider this:

```
std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3};
std::vector<int> v1(3); //v1 has initial size!!
std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(v1));
```

Now v1 will be 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, because `back_inserter` `push_back`s. If you have already allocated the necessary size in the destination, then use the `begin()` iterator and not the `back_insert_iterator`:

```
std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3};
std::vector<int> v1(3); //v1 has initial size!!
std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), v1.begin()); //use begin here
```

v1 is 1, 2, 3, as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it really confuses me. May I ask another question? When I modify grid[i][j].reserve(a.grid[i][j].size()); to grid[i][j].resize(a.grid[i][j].size()); and use back_inserter, It will also work fine. What's difference reserve and resize? I know reserver is just keep a buffer and resize will initialize the value. But why resize will work correctly?

Comment: @Josper: I don't think anything you do with grid[i][j], be it resize of reserve will have any effect. All that matters is whether or not you resize grid itself

Comment: Which one of these is more efficient?

Comment: @nog642: The one which uses the back_inserter may suffer from several reallocations

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan What about using the back_inserter method with a call to reserve() beforehand? Would that be essentially the same as the initial size method, or is there a reason to prefer one over the other?